# How do I force my while loop that is reading a line to not stop before 3 empty lines?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have this while loop that is reading a `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println (line);
}
```

I know it is going to stop as soon as the line is null, but in this case (the data I am reading), there are some new lines and then the data continues.

Hence, I want the while loop to stop executing once it has found **3 empty lines** in a row (for then I am sure that the data is finished).

Thank you

Comment: maintain a count variable, increment it everytime you find empty line and set it to 0 everytime you find a line with some value

Comment: have you tried this? IMHO readline will return "", but not null. It return null only when the "end of stream was reached"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving @user2004685's answer, you can count the number of empty lines:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
int emptyCount = 0;

String line;
while (emptyCount < 3 && (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println (line);

     /* Track Empty Lines Count */
     if(String.isEmpty(line)) {
          emptyCount++;
     } else {
          emptyCount = 0;
     }
}
```

Don't forget to reset `emptyCount` to 0, otherwise it'll exit too soon in case you'd have line,emty,line,empty,line,empty,line,empty,line,empty...

Comment: You can comment on the original answer rather than posting the same answer again and adding a footnote.

Comment: Is there a way to print everything there is on br? I tried using a while (true), but it didnt work as I intented.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please update the question by adding example input, with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Keep a track of the empty lines and add an additional condition to your loop.

Try this piece of code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
int emptyCount = 0;

String line = null;
while (emptyCount < 3 && (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println (line);
     /* Track Empty Lines Count */
     if(String.isEmpty(line)) {
          emptyCount++;
     } else {
          emptyCount = 0;
     }
}
```

**Update:**
I have overlooked "3 empty lines after *each other*". Updated the solution as per Gavriel's comment.

Thanks Gavriel!